# Searching HTML5 data attributes using wildcards in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have the following list of elements that uses the HTML 5 data attributes.

```
<div data-element="INFO-NAME"></div>
<div data-element="INFO-EMAIL"></div>
<div data-element="INFO-ADDRESS"></div>
<div data-element="INFO-ZIP"></div>
```

What I would like to do is to get the list of all the elements that contains

`data-element="INFO-*"`

I tried `$('[data-element="INFO-*"]')` but this returns an empty object. How can I retrieve this list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
 $('[data-element^="INFO-"]')
```

which means find any element with attribute `data-element` with a value starting with `INFO-`

See more at http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings

Answer (score 5):

Use `^=`, which means the «starting from»:

```
$('[data-element^="INFO-"]')
```

Comment: The `-*` is not required.

Comment: Is there a generic way of matching part of a data-element value?  for example, data-element=Info1,Info2,Info3... how to match [data-element=*Info1*] ??

Comment: @RyanGriggs I think what you're looking for is `[data-element*="Info1"]`, which reads _data-element contains "Info1"_